# Build a conda package that creates a conda environment from env.yaml file

Tags: python, linux, bash, anaconda, conda

I want to build a custom conda package that upon running `conda install <package_name>` would create a new conda environment. I wanted to use a environment.yaml file for this purpose. Unfortunately, I can't find any documentation that let's me run `conda create -n <env_name> -f environment.yaml` inside the recipe. Is there any way I could call such commands inside the recipe?

I am a beginner in conda and thus, please bear with my loose terminology.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, and would be quite unexpected as an end user. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @darthbith I want to distribute updated conda environments to users and thought of using conda to manage the distribution of those environments by creating a package that can install/update them for me. But it somehow feels hacky now.

Comment: You can create what's called a "meta-package" if you want to distribute a particular set of dependencies to your users. This is that the `anaconda` package is. https://conda.io/docs/commands/build/conda-metapackage.html

Comment: @darthbith as far as I am aware, meta-pacakges only work for dependencies that are available as conda packages themselves. Or do they now also support pip? Because some of the packages installed in my env are from pip.

Comment: Does this help: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-cloud/user-guide/tasks/work-with-environments ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not and expert in conda and don't know if this is the better way to solve this, but in case it helps someone, I had the same problem, and I solved it out including the depedencies (conda and pip) in a environment.yam, and call conda update in the build.sh.

1. Include dependencies in a file called environment.yml.
2. Make sure, the environment.yml is included in a folder referenced in the source section of the meta.yaml.
3. Call conda update in the build.sh: `conda env update -f=environment.yml`